# How can I see some sample text rendered in all fonts on my system?

Tags: windows, fonts, typeface

I want to choose a font (technically, a [typeface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface) or font-family) out the numerous ones I have on my (Windows) system, for use in some (non-TeX) application, e.g. LO Writer.

To do this, I want to be able to see some text ("Quick brown fox" or some such) rendered with *all* the fonts I have installed. Of course, non-Latin fonts need text which showcases the relevant glyphs and glyph combinations (e.g. continued forms in Arabic, punctuation and cantilation marks in Hebrew).

What's a good way to get this done?

Bonus questions for 1337 users:

- Linux, not just Windows
- Limit this to only the Hebrew fonts, only the Arabic fonts, only the Latin fonts etc.

Comment: Do we assume that you do not already have nirsofts FontView? http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_fonts_viewer.html  Like what would you want that you cannot accomplish with that?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Will try that.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick supports rendering arbitrary fonts and text. Below is a sample script that will iterate over available fonts and render some text. I'm not sure how bash savvy you are, so I'll just and assume that the script makes sense.

I ran this in Cygwin and Gentoo so it's a viable solution for both systems. It's not perfect though, because `convert.exe` is unable to handle all fonts (on both systems). I guess they must be TrueType. Check the docs for options to the convert program (antialiasing, cropping). Feel free to update the script if you find some useful options.

**File: fonts.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
t="
NAME
   cowsay/cowthink - configurable speaking/thinking cow (and a bit more)

SYNOPSIS
   cowsay [-e eye_string] [-f cowfile] [-h] [-l] [-n] [-T tongue_string] 
   [-W column] [-bdgpstwy]

DESCRIPTION
   Cowsay  generates  an  ASCII  picture of a cow saying something provided 
   by the user.  If run with no arguments, it accepts standard input, word-
   wraps the message given at about 40  columns,  and  prints the cow saying
   the given message on standard output.

- - - 

~ \` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + [ ] { } ; : ' \" , . < > / ? \\ /

"
```

> `# . . .`

```
CONVERT="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ImageMagick-6.8.4-Q16/convert.exe"
LIM=${1:-23}

if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then rm -f Fonts/*; fi
if [ ! -d Fonts ]; then mkdir Fonts; fi

"$CONVERT" -list font| awk '/Font/ {print $2}' | head -n$LIM | sort -R |
while read f ;do 

    let n=n+1
    printf "%4d/%-4d %s\n" $n $LIM "$f"

    out="Fonts/$f.png"
    txt="Fonts/txt.z"
    err="Fonts/$f.err.txt"

    if [ ! -f "$out" ] && [ ! -f "$err" ]; then    
        echo -e "$f\n" > $txt
        cat "$0" |sed 's/\t/    /g'>> $txt
        "$CONVERT"  \
            -page a3 -font "$f" \
                -kerning 0 -density 90 -pointsize 16 -interline-spacing -2 \
            -trim +repage  -bordercolor white  -border 5 \
            text:$txt \
            "$out" 2> "$err"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            printf "%9s %s\n" " " ERROR

            else    rm -f "$err" ;fi
    else
            printf "%9s %s\n" " " SKIPPING
    fi
done
```

**Sample output**

```
$ time sh fonts.sh  234 clean
   1/234  Candara-Italic
   2/234  Gabriola
   3/234  Candara-Bold
          SKIPPING
   4/234  Lucida-Sans-Unicode
   5/234  Corbel-Bold
   6/234  LilyUPC-Italic
   7/234  FreesiaUPC-Bold-Italic
   8/234  Kartika
   9/234  FreesiaUPC
  10/234  JasmineUPC-Italic
  ✂ (...)
  41/234  Courier-Oblique
          ERROR
  42/234  Helvetica
          ERROR
  ✂ (...)
 real    4m22.149s    
 
 $ du -h Fonts
 361M    Fonts
```

---

[image: Terminus]

---

[image: ProFont]

referencess:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#text
[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)